# React Native issue: Module does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a native module and created another project to test it locally.

Here are my steps:

`cd <Testing project>
npm install ../<Module project>
react-native link <module name>
react-native run-android`

Then I got following error:

```
 error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-helloworld` from `G:\Test\App.js`: Module `react-native-helloworld` does not exist in the Haste module map

    This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
    To resolve try the following:
      1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
      2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
      3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
      4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
```

[image]

I've searched StackOverflow for the issue, but there's no workable solution. The suggested solution '**clear the cache and reset everything**' cannot work.

However, the module can work if I publish it to https://www.npmjs.com/ and then install it via `npm install <module name>`.

The only difference is the installing way.

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I wanted to fork a package from npm and modify it. In the end I just gave up because of the hacky workarounds needed.

Comment: @yushulx did you find the resolution for it ?

Comment: @Amitk No. I've given up React Native and started to use Flutter :)

Comment: @yushulx lol. this is also my next move. thx for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error complaining about how it could not find 'path' from where ever it was looking for. In the end I figured out that the issue was completely unrelated.The following auto import was accidentally added to my code (probably when I was creating a style using 'textTransform')

```
import { transform } from "@babel/core";
```

Once I noticed that and removed it, the project was buildable. It might help to check recent changes in your code to see if something similar got added.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you're accidentaly symlinking your library inside node_modules when you use npm, instead of using npm you can use yarn

```
yarn add file:../<module_project>
```

Comment: `file:` prefix is optional it seems, it works either way